# Because translator depends on translator, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart

when i'm trying to import translator package into main.dart file i get this problem ,

"**Because translator depends on translator, version solving failed**"

how can i solve it ??

i'm building a live-time translator app

Comment: Is your package (i.e. your app) also named "translator"?  If so, `pub` will think that your app depends on itself.  Pick a different name.

Comment: yes, my app name is "translator", i will rename it.